# Can't render inside a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, components, jsx

I have a map function that is supposed to return a component with the deconstructed properties
the map itself works, i receive all the right values when i console log them. But when i pass them down to the component and insert them in the return, nothing gets rendered.

Parent component:

```
export default function List({ activities }) {
  function renderThings() {
    activities.map((activity) => {
      const {
        title,
        price
      } = activity;
    
      return (
        <li>
          <Activity
            title={title}
            price={price}
          />
        </li>
      );
    });
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="List">{renderThings()}</ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Activity/ child Component:

```
export default function Activity({
  title,
  price,
}) {

  return (
    <div className="list-item">
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <p>{price}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I don't see where I am going wrong

Comment: Your function `renderThings` does not return anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `return` the `Array.prototype.map` result:

```
return activities.map((activity) => {
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This code will be working fine.

```
export default function List({ activities }) {
  function renderThings() {
    return activities.map((activity) => {
      const {
        title,
        price
      } = activity;

      return (
        <li>
           <Activity
             title={title}
             price={price}
           />
         </li>
       );
     });
   }
   return (
     <div>
       <ul className="List">{renderThings()}</ul>
     </div>
   );
 }
 Activity/ child Component:

     export default function Activity({
   title,
   price,
 }) {

   return (
     <div className="list-item">
       <h1>{title}</h1>
       <p>{price}</p>
     </div>
   );
 }
```

Comment: What does this answer provide that the other does not? At the very least you should include *why* your provided code will work..